# Using pp (Pretty Print) in a method before save allows my model to save successfully, it fails otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pretty-print

## I have an object that looks like this:

It is used to allows users with `resumes` to 'apply to' (job)`listings`.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: jobapps
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  denied     :boolean
#  listing_id :integer
#  resume_id  :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Jobapp < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  belongs_to :resume
  validates_uniqueness_of :listing_id, scope: :resume_id
  before_save :default_values

  . . .

private

  def default_values
    if self.denied.nil?
      self.denied = false
    end
  end
end
```

**Whenever I create a new `Jobapp` object, the job always fails.**

*If I change the `default_values` method on the `Jobapps` model to:*

```
def default_values
  if denied.nil?
    self.denied = false
    pp self
  end
end
```

**The object is created and saved.**

---

### Console Output:

When I attempt to have a `Resume` object `apply_to` a `Listing` object, which should create a `Jobapp` object:

```
Started POST "/listings/1/apply?resume=8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-31 18:43:33 -0500
Processing by ListingsController#apply as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"htbHjaZnkqRMfgSUAQA5zOXB3ax/MAaHRUx8jRWr/lw=", "resume"=>"8", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Listing Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Resume Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "resumes".* FROM "resumes" WHERE "resumes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "8"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Jobapp Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "jobapps" WHERE ("jobapps"."listing_id" = 1 AND "jobapps"."resume_id" = 8) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/listings/1
Completed 302 Found in 102ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

When I have the `pp self` line in the `default_values` method:

```
Started POST "/listings/1/apply?resume=8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-31 18:41:36 -0500
Processing by ListingsController#apply as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"htbHjaZnkqRMfgSUAQA5zOXB3ax/MAaHRUx8jRWr/lw=", "resume"=>"8", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Listing Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (2.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Resume Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "resumes".* FROM "resumes" WHERE "resumes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "8"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Jobapp Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "jobapps" WHERE ("jobapps"."listing_id" = 1 AND "jobapps"."resume_id" = 8) LIMIT 1
"here it is"
#<Jobapp id: nil, denied: false, listing_id: 1, resume_id: 8, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "jobapps" ("created_at", "denied", "listing_id", "resume_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Thu, 31 Jul 2014 23:41:36 UTC +00:00], ["denied", false], ["listing_id", 1], ["resume_id", 8], ["updated_at", Thu, 31 Jul 2014 23:41:36 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/listings/1
Completed 302 Found in 120ms (ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
```

---

### Some referenced methods:

Here is the `apply` method from the controller:

```
def apply
  set_resume
  if @resume.apply_to(@listing)
    redirect_to @listing
  else
    redirect_to @listing, alert: 'Unable to apply for job'
  end
end
```

Here is the `Resume.apply_to` method:

```
def apply_to(listing)
  jobapp = Jobapp.new(resume: self, listing: listing)
  jobapp.save
end
```

---

### Notes:

It smells like I'm doing something weird with the conditional `apply` method (which is annoying) but I don't think that's the reason for the failure (it fails if I take out the odd conditional and simplify the `Resume.apply_to` method to simply `create` the object rather than using `new` then `save`.

- [Pretty Print ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, this is because `self.denied = false` returns false, and so your callback is returning false, which will cancel all future callbacks and associated action:

> **If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled**. If an after_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks are cancelled. Callbacks are generally run in the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as methods on the model, which are called last.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Just make sure your `default_values` method returns true.

Comment: This is definitely the problem.  I changed the method to include `return true` at the end and it passes.  I can't think of a different solution, so this will have to do.

Comment: @Ecnalyr Returning `self` is another option, or you could use `assign_attributes(denied: false)` which returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ActiveRecord Callbacks documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled.

And in your callback you have:

```
if self.denied.nil?
  self.denied = false
end
```

So if you keep in mind that all blocks (including if blocks, methods, begin/end blocks, etc.) return the last value in the block... then you're affectively returning `false` from your callback. That is:

1. `self.denied = false` sets `self.denied` to false an then returns `false`
2. The `if` block surrounding this returns the last value in the block, or `false`
3. The method returns the last value in the method (block), or `false`
4. Therefore, your callback cancels the `save` operation.

Furthermore, when you introduced the `pp self` statement, then that will effectively output `self` and then return `self`, which is not `false` (obviously).

So to fix the non `pp self` version, I would recommend just returning `true` at the end since you're most likely not looking to abort the `save` after evaluating the contents of your callback method. Here it is, slightly simplifed using the idiomatic `||=` operator.

```
def default_values
  self.denied ||= false
  true
end
```

The use of `||=` above is the same as: `self.denied || self.denied = false`.